# JQuery FadeIn doesn't work in php file

Tags: php, jquery, fadein

I am trying to use fadeIn() method in php file, it is exactly same code as HTML but not working.

1. Here is working example:

--------------------------

```
function hide(){
$("#fade").hide().fadeIn(5000);
}
```

---------------------------------

```
<div id="click"><button type="submit" value="3" name="submit"     onclick="hide();">click</button> </div>
<div id="fade"><button type="submit" value="3" name="submit">Skip >></button></div>
```

Once click the "click" button, Skip button fades in. It works totally fine.

But the same code in my php file not working. The code is exactly same It seems JQuery function is not called. Do I have to change anything to put Jquery in php file? Please give me a help.

thank you!

-------------------------added--------------------------
Here is code with php, the hide() function is same. I am trying to call fade-in function for the button in and outside of the form(with id="fade"), and both are not working.

Thank you for your help.

```
<div id="click"><button type="button" value="3" name="submit" onclick="hide(); return false;">click</button></div>
<div id="fade"><button type="submit" value="3" name="submit">Skip >></button></div>
<div id="skip">
<form method="post" >
<input type="hidden" id="skip_ig" name="skip_ig" value=""></input>
<div id="fade"><button type="submit" value="3" name="submit">Skip >></button></div>
 <?php
     include('includes/aftersubmit.php');
                                        ?>         
   </form>
   </div>
```

Comment: I for one, am not seeing any PHP in here. Please **re-tag** or include your PHP `code`.

Comment: Yes, I added php code

Comment: @Taewan please add the aftersubmit.php code. I got this to work fine for me, so i think the error must be in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to do with PHP. The buttons of type `type="submit"` submits the page before executing the javascript / jquery.

Look at using `preventDefault();`

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Or a dirty fix use a `return false;` like so:

`onclick="hide();return false;"`

I would, however, discourage you mixing up your HTML and JavaScript together using the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: Thanks! it is very useful but did not help my function

Comment: In your browser console window (f12 in chrome & IE) check the console tab for any errors or warning.

Answer (score 0):

If your hide function is inside the `<?php ?>` tags, then it will think that it is a php function **not** a javascript function.

```
<?php
    php stuff goes here
?>

HTML/Javascript goes OUTSIDE the php tags

function hide(){
    $("#fade").hide().fadeIn(5000);
}
```

This might be what is going on, depending on what your php file looks like

Answer (score 0):

Just prevent the default submit action..

```
function hide(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#fade").hide().fadeIn(5000);
 }
```

But somehow, I doubt thats what you really want...

Comment: Thanks. I wish this can fix my problem but it wouldn't

Comment: Ok, well what exactly is the problem..just that when the page refreshes it doesn't fadeIn?

Comment: When I click on the button which supposed to call fadeIn function, nothing has been changed. Seems the function has not called

Comment: Is the Jquery on that php page as well?? Like the actual script/function